# Path to file or stream?

Tags: c++, architecture

I was discussing with a co-worker and I thought this would be a good question to put here on SO.

When designing and API when should your functions accept file paths and when should they accept streams? Are there any guidelines?

```
void do_something(const std::filesystem::path &file_path);
void do_something(std::istream &stream);
```

path:

- callee is responsible for checking that the file exists and is accessible.
- is difficult to unit test. You have to create/have a file on disk to test it.

stream:

- caller is responsible for checking that the file exists and is accessible. more repetitive boilerplate code.
- unit test is easier you can just pass a stream object

I guess one could add a function to the library to "help" open the file, something of the sorts:

```
std::ifstream open_input(const std::filesystem::path &file)
{
    std::ifstream stream(file);

    if (not stream) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("failed to open file: " + file.string());
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I have personally always used a path because then I can check the type, eg ".txt"

Comment: I am afraid that the question will be closed as  too broad or opinion based. Nevertheless, I definitely prefer the second version as it is much more flexible (it may work with other streams), and obeys SRP. In fact, I would consider going one step further, and make an API iterator-based.

Comment: @user58697 iterator-based when dealing with files?

Comment: @Mac Yes, why not? See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator for example.

Comment: Your helper function must `return std::move(stream);` or it will not compile.

Comment: @Eugene compiles fine: http://ideone.com/3lgXNn

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You stated yourself that you could add the "helper" function in order to preserve the istream interface. This is also the better solution in terms of testability and adheres to the single responsibility principle ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Your helper function has one responsibility (create stream from file) and your actual function another (it "does something" :)).

I'd add that it depends on the context of what does something actually does. For example, if it is a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for different accesses to an underlying functionality, then it would make sense to have that interface with the actual path. Still you would have a separate helper function and a do_something function which are used from the facade.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your cake and eat it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

//
// some booilerplate to allow use of a polymorphic temporary
template<class Stream, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::istream, Stream>::value> * = nullptr>
struct stream_holder
{
  stream_holder(Stream stream) : stream_(std::move(stream)) {}
  operator std::istream&() && { return stream_; }
  operator std::istream&() & { return stream_; }

  private:
  Stream stream_;
};

// helper function
template<class Stream, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::istream, Stream>::value> * = nullptr>
auto with_this(Stream&& stream)
{
  return stream_holder<std::decay_t<Stream>>(std::forward<Stream>(stream));
}



// express logic in terms of stream
void do_something(std::istream& stream_ref);

// utility functions to create various types of stream
std::ifstream file_stream();
std::stringstream string_stream();


int main()
{

  // * composability with succinct syntax
  // * lifetime automatically managed
  // * no repetitive boilerplate
  do_something(with_this(file_stream()));
  do_something(with_this(string_stream()));
}
```